# both the "ResolvePackageAssets" and the "ResolvePackageDependencies task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#

I've had this error after doing a hard reset on my code from GitHub then pulling it again.
Also the same error but with "ResolvePackageDependencies" happened.
Can anyone help?
Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was simply solving by updating Visual Studio, for some reason the first time I searched for updates there was none, but after restarting the PC, could see VS wasn't updated.